# Enumerated classes

Tags: c++, templates

I have happened upon the following pattern, and wondered if there is a name for it?

An `enum` defines the concrete classes:

```
enum Fruits{ eApple, eBanana };
```

And a templated `struct` provides the interface:

```
template< Fruit T >
struct SomeFruit {
    void eatIt() { // assert failure };
};
```

We can then implement the concrete classes thus:

```
template<>
struct SomeFruit< eApple > {
    void eatIt() { // eat an apple };
};

template<>
struct SomeFruit< eBanana > {
    void eatIt() { // eat a banana };
};
```

And use them thus:

```
SomeFruit< eApple> apple;
apple.eatIt();
```

Comment: i think this part is useless: "We can then implement the concrete classes thus:". concrete class is implemented using `SomeFruit< eApple> apple;`

Comment: Why not just make an `Apple` and `Banana` class?

Comment: @Andrey: Notice that without that part calling `apple.eatIt()` will result in `assert failure`, and not `eat an apple`.

Comment: @Gman: This pattern is interesting to me because we have a strict ordering over the concrete classes which implement `SomeFruit`, namely the order in which they appear in the `enum`. Such an ordering is not present between siblings in a vanilla class hierarchy.

Comment: you are right, it is more complicated then i thought

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's usually used like this (to catch errors at compile-time)

```
template< Fruit T >
struct SomeFruit;

template<>
struct SomeFruit< eApple > {
    void eatIt() { // eat an apple };
};

template<>
struct SomeFruit< eBanana > {
    void eatIt() { // eat a banana };
};
```

and often called ***compile-time polymorphism*** (as opposed to *run-time polymorphism*, which in C++ is achieved using virtual functions).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the name, but you are better with not implementing the template - just declaring it will throw a compilation error if someone tries to instantiate :

```
template< Fruit T >
struct SomeFruit;
```

Comment: Yes that is a pleasant side effect of this pattern, such an error would be equivalent to "cannot instantiate abstract class" with vanilla classes.

Comment: @Dave Tapley - yes, it depends what you want. Compile or run-time error.

Answer (score 0):

This is called template specialization. In this case it is explicit (aka full) specialization, which is recognized by `template <>`, as opposed to partial specialization.

Comment: Correct, however I am interested in the pattern obtained when using an `enum` for the template parameter, and providing full specialisation for each value of the `enum`.

Comment: @Dave Tapley: Never have come across a specific name for that, interesting if others have...