# Call methods on class templatized over enum

Tags: c++, templates, enums

Given the following code:

```
enum Fruits{ eApple, eBanana };

template<>
struct SomeFruit< eApple > {
    void eatIt() { // eat an apple };
};

template<>
struct SomeFruit< eBanana > {
    void eatIt() { // eat a banana };
};
```

Is there a way to call the explicitly specialized `eatIt()`, for each of `Fruits`, without having to make each call manually?

My definition of "make each call manually" would be:

```
void eatAllFruits()
{
    SomeFruit< eApple > apple;   
    apple.eatIt(); 
    SomeFruit< eBanana > banana; 
    banana.eatIt(); 
}
```

Clearly with this method one has to extend `eatAllFruits` everytime `Fruits` is modified.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you want to do, but it sounds like you want to use virtual functions.

Comment: @Adam Rosenfield: I am really just interested in this pattern, this question follows on from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997038/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly thanks to [Noah Roberts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035088/call-methods-on-class-templatized-over-enum/4035283#4035283)' answer which deserves as an upvote for being the inspiration to this answer.

Following on from his answer I extracted and refactored `boost::mpl::for_each` and `boost::mpl::range` to obtain what I believe is the minimal complete definition which satisfies the question's criteria. It has no longer has any dependancy on Boost and is used as such:

```
struct eat_fruit; // As Noah's answer

void eatAllFruit()  
{  
    EnumIteration< Fruits, eApple, eTotal >::for_each( eat_fruit() );
}
```

My `EnumIteration` struct is defined as below, and I welcome any comments or improvements. The only notable difference to the Boost version is that the range excludes the final enum value (i.e. `eTotal`), unlike `boost::mpl::range` which includes it.

```
template< typename ENUM, ENUM BEGIN, ENUM END >
struct EnumIteration
{
private:
    template< ENUM N >
    struct Iterator
    {
        static const ENUM value = N;
        typedef Iterator< static_cast< ENUM >( N+1 ) > next;
        operator ENUM() const { return static_cast< ENUM >( this->value ); } 
    };

    template< typename T >
    struct End 
    { enum { value = false }; };

    template<>
    struct End< Iterator< END > >
    { enum { value = true }; };

    template< bool done = true >
    struct for_each_impl
    {
        template< typename Iterator, typename F >
        static void execute( Iterator*, F ) {}
    };

    template<>
    struct for_each_impl<false>
    {
        template< typename Iterator, typename F >
        static void execute( Iterator*, F f )
        {
            f( typename Iterator() );
            typedef typename Iterator::next next;
            for_each_impl< End< next >::value >::execute( static_cast< next * >( 0 ), f );
        }
    };

public:
    template< typename F >
    static void for_each( F f )
    {
        typedef Iterator< BEGIN > first;
        for_each_impl< End< first >::value >::execute( static_cast< first * >( 0 ), f );
    }
};
```

Comment: I just received a [C4239](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/186yxbac), this can be avoided by changing `eat_fruit::operator() (Index&)` to `eat_fruit::operator() (Index const&)`.

Answer (score 4):

My guess at this point is that you want to iterate over enum fruit automatically.  There is, in fact, a way to do this.  Have a look at this article I blogged regarding a somewhat similar problem: http://crazyeddiecpp.blogspot.com/2010/02/using-mplforeach-to-fill-tuple.html

Note the use of mpl::range and mpl::for_each.

Thus your eatSomeFruit() function would look something like so:

```
// modify enum...
enum Fruits { eApple, eBananna, eFruitLast = eBananna };

struct eat_fruit
{
  template < typename Index >
  void operator() (Index&)
  {
    SomeFruit<Index::value> eater;
    eater.eatIt();
  }
};

void eatSomeFruit()
{
  mpl::for_each< mpl::range<0, eFruitLast> >(eat_fruit());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason they're called templates is that they're not actual code - they're templates that tell the compiler what the code should look like, once you supply the missing pieces. There's no way to get the compiler to create the code without writing some other code that calls it explicitly.

Comment: Yes, however I don't see what the "missing pieces" are here. I understand that it may not be possible within the constraints of C++, but I believe all the information the compiler could need to do what I have asked is available at compile time.

Comment: @Dave, the "missing pieces" are the template parameters.

Comment: ah yes I see what you mean. But in this case the template parameters are the enum values, which are available at compile time, see my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe make use of a template function?

```
template<typename F> void eatIt(F f) { /* eat it */ }
```

[@Dave]

```
enum somename
{
val1 = -1,
val2, // this will be = 0
...
};
```

somename is now a 'type' (the val# are int - they can be negative numbers) and you can use it to create variables of the type somename.

Comment: Could you expand upon this? Notice that in my question the template parameter is a `Fruits` (so we can think of it as an `unsigned int`) and not a `typename`.

Comment: That is what typename F represent (int - enum's are int's)